# Russian Recipe Help Needed!

Tags: baking

I need help converting this recipe and it's measurements into English! https://pin.it/30QV1w9

[image]

Comment: I think this question is likely to be closed as off-topic, as it is a translation request, and not so much a question about cooking. There is a Russian language Stack Exchange site, but note that [the rules for that site](https://russian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) requires that you put in effort to translate first. They offer *assistance* with translations, but do not provide transitions-as-a-service.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a translation question and belongs on Russian SE

Answer (score 3):

Here are the translations.

Original:

- Печенье 300 гр.
- сгущёнка 2 ст.л
- творог 250 гр.
- сметана  2 ст.л
- Бананы 2
- Мандарин 4
- киви 2
- клубника 5-6

Translated to English:

- Cookies 300 gr.
- Sweetened condensed milk 2 tbsp
- Cottage cheese 250 gr.
- Sour cream 2 tbsp.
- Bananas 2
- Mandarin 4
- Kiwi 2
- Strawberries 5 - 6

Comment: A mistake at sour cream. it's 2 tablespoons, not 250 gr. 250g is only mentioned once in the screenshot

Comment: Looks kind of tasty!